# Using 2 while loop and move next in PHP

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

can any one help me to use 2 while loop conditions with 2 move next?

```
<?
$condition1=$core_db->Execute("select Husbandname, age, marriedto from 
husbands");
$condition2=$core_db->Execute("select age, marriedto from wifes where 
wifename=?", array($condition1->fields[2]));;

echo 'any';
while(!$condition1->EOF){   
    echo 'any';
    $condition1->MoveNext();
};
?>
```

my above example is showing husband name and age from table husbands, now i want to grab wife data from wifes table in the same loop using movenext to give all members data.

Any idea?

Comment: Update your question there is no `condition2` present in your code.

Comment: You mean you want to have while-loop2 inside of while-loop 1?

Comment: i want to use while(!$condition1->EOF){   and condition 2 and use condition1 and 2 movenext

Comment: while(!$condition1->EOF && !condition2->EOF){  I think it's like this but now the second part with movenext how it can be movenext for both condition 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into **JOINS**: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

You basically mean that you want one SQL-statement and one while-loop (If I understood you correctly)

```
<?
$condition=$core_db->Execute("select * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id");

echo 'any';
while(!$condition->EOF){   
    echo 'any';
    $condition->MoveNext();
};

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your update:

```
$condition1=$core_db->Execute("select Husbandname, age, 
marriedto from husbands");
$condition2=$core_db->Execute("select age, 
marriedto from wifes where wifename=?", array($condition1->fields[2]));
```

I would do something like this (*The SQL way*):

```
$condition = $core_db->Execute("select husbands.Husbandname, 
husbands.age, husbands.marriedto, wifes.id, wifes.age, wifes.marriedto from 
husbands INNER JOIN husbands.marriedto = wifes.id");

while(!$condition->EOF){   
    echo 'any';
    $condition->MoveNext();
};
```

If you want to do this in PHP instead of SQL you could do something like (*I would recommend the SQL - way*)

```
<?
$condition1=$core_db->Execute("select Husbandname, age, 
marriedto from husbands");

echo 'any';
while(!$condition1->EOF){   
    $condition2=$core_db->Execute("select age, 
    marriedto from wifes where wifename=?", array($condition1->fields[2]));

    echo 'any';
    $condition1->MoveNext();
};

?>
```

Comment: I updated the question maybe it will give better idea

Comment: I use php script so i want to know if i'll make html table and i want to show data like

Husbandname | wife | his age | her age

how to define every one as php, in my upper example it was $husband = $condition1->fields[0]

Comment: Both ways are PHP but the SQL-way uses SQL-query to combine your query and use one loop instead of two. That is much more effective and better pratice.

Comment: I think your php way is working super with me, is there's way to make in php if married to null echo ' '; to show nothing?

Comment: I don't know how you grab the actual fieldvalues but it would be something like if ($condition2[$fieldvalue] != null) {echo $fieldvalue}. (echo '' would not be needed)

Comment: if ($married != null) {code}. else {other code}.. If you just want to echo '' in other code - it wont be needed because echo '' does nothing for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean somethng like that:

```
<?
  $condition1=$core_db->Execute("select ANY from Any");
  $condition2=$core_db->Execute("select ANY from Any");

        while(!$condition1->EOF || !condition2->EOF){   
            if (!$condition1->EOF) {
                // Code for condition1...
                $condition1->MoveNext();
            }
            if (!$condition2->EOF) {
                // Code for condition2...
                $condition2->MoveNext();
            }
        };
?>
```

but that is normaly not the right way (handle to queries in one loop)

Comment: nope i don't want to use them separated, i want to use them as 1 condition
to show data from 2 different DB table in 1 code.

Comment: Two tables of the same or similar structure in a row (UNION?) Or in parallel next to each other if the tables have a relation (JOIN)?

Comment: can you read the comments in the other answer, it will give you a better idea of what I need, thanks for help.